# How to create a timer with text mode control in the Tcl / Tk language

Tags: linux, loops, time, tcl, tk-toolkit

What I want is something similar to this bash shell script just below:

## Shell Bash

```
#!/bin/bash
# shell timer
# Note: Do not measure time precisely because there is loss in calculations and other commands
# For a human being is something almost imperceptible, fortunately.
# ------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------
s=00
m=00
h=00

key=""

function _screen() {
clear
# Shows the elapsed time on the terminal screen and plays to the time.txt file always updating
printf "%02d:%02d:%02d" $h $m $s > ~/time.txt
  echo ":: 'p' to pause, 'c' to continue and 's' to exit ::"
}

function _time() {
    _screen
  sleep 1
  s=$((s+1))
  [ $s -eq 60 ] && m=$((m+1)) && s=00
  [ $m -eq 60 ] && h=$((h+1)) && m=00
}

function _pause() {
while :
do
    _screen
    sleep 1
    read key
    [ "$key" = "c" ] && clear && break
done
}

function _main() {

# Put the terminal in special character interpretation mode
stty -echo -icanon min 0

while :
do
    [ "$key" = "s" ] && break   
    [ "$key" = "p" ] && _pause
    _time
    read key
done

# Restores the default mode
stty sane

exit 0
}
_main
```

---

Perhaps the most obvious is to convert it to Tcl/Tk. I even tried, but I still did not succeed. See:

## Shell Tclsh

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
# shell timer
# Note: Do not measure time precisely because there is loss in calculations and other commands
# For a human being is something almost imperceptible, fortunately.
# ------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------
set s 00
set m 00
set h 00

puts -nonewline ""
flush stdout
set key [gets stdin]

proc _screen{ } {
clear


set archive [open [pwd]/time.txt w]

# Shows the elapsed time on the terminal screen and plays to the time.txt file always updating
puts $archive "%02d:%02d:%02d" $h $m $s" 
puts -nonewline ":: 'p' to pause, 'c' to continue and 's' to exit ::"


}

proc _time{ } {
    _screen
  after 1000
  s=[expr s+1]
  if { $s -eq 60 } { m=[expr m+1] } { s=00 }
  if { $m -eq 60 } { h=[expr h+1] } { m=00 }
}

proc _pause{ } {
while { 1 } 
{
    _screen
  after 1000
    $argv key
    if { "$key" = "c" } { break }
  }
}

proc _main{ } {

# Put the terminal in special character interpretation mode
stty -echo -icanon min 0

while { 1 } 
{
    if { "$key" = "s" } { break }
    if { "$key" = "p" } { _pause }
    _time
    $argv key

}

# Restores the default mode
stty sane
close $archive
exit 0
}
after 1000 _main
```

I'm still committed and working for this to work identically to the example quoted - bash script. But do not rule out improvements and suggestions that you can promote.

> What I have in mind something like:

[image]

If someone here knows and wants to share the idea, feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your Tcl code:

- `proc _pause{ } {` -- Tcl is very whitespace sensitive, so you need to separate the procedure name from the argument list
- `s=[expr s+1]` -- use `set` to set variables, and you need to use `$s` to get the variable *value*: `set s [expr {$s+1}]` or in this case use the [incr](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/incr.htm) command `incr s`
- `if { $s -eq 60 }` and `if { "$key" = "s" }` -- see the [expr](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm) man page for the correct operators. 
  You want `{$s == 60}` and `{$key eq "s"}`
- `stty -echo -icanon min 0` -- stty is an external command, so you need `exec stty ...`

Those are the main syntax problems. Your indentation style can be improved so you code can be readable and maintainable.

---

I thought this was an interesting challenge so I decided to implement it independently of your code. Let me know if you have any questions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set seconds 0
set running true
array set status {
    false "(paused)"
    true  "        "
}

#################################################################
proc main {} {
    enableRaw

    puts "'p' to pause; 'c' to continue; 'q' to quit"
    every 1000 display_time

    chan configure stdout -buffering none
    chan configure stdin -blocking no -buffering none
    chan event stdin readable handleStdin

    vwait ::forever

    disableRaw
    puts ""
}

# ref https://wiki.tcl.tk/14693
proc enableRaw {{channel stdin}} {
    exec /bin/stty raw -echo <@$channel
}
proc disableRaw {{channel stdin}} {
    exec /bin/stty -raw echo <@$channel
}

proc every {ms code} {
    after $ms [list every $ms $code]
    uplevel #0 $code
}

proc display_time {{event ""}} {
    global running seconds
    puts -nonewline "\r [format_time] $::status($running) "
    if {$running && $event eq ""} {incr seconds}
}

proc format_time {} {
    return [clock format $::seconds -format "%H:%M:%S" -gmt true]
}

proc handleStdin {} {
    set data [chan read stdin 1]
    switch -- $data {
        P - p {set ::running false; display_time}
        C - c {set ::running true;  display_time unpausing}
        Q - q {set ::forever "now"}
    }
}

#################################################################
main
```

Comment: What version of Tcl are you running? `puts [info patchlevel]` -- it's clearly an old version: why?

Comment: solution: replace `chan configure` with `fconfigure`; replace `chan event` with `fileevent`; replace `chan read` with `read`

Comment: What version of Tcl are I running? **Tcl/Tk 8.4** . I suspect that the crash you are the same for the account of a version of Tcl.

Comment: That's what `stty raw` is meant to fix, so you don't need to hit enter

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight modification of `enableRaw` and `disableRaw` that doesn't `exec` for `stty`:

```
package require term::ansi::ctrl::unix

proc enableRaw {} {
    term::ansi::ctrl::unix::raw
}

proc diableRaw {} {
    term::ansi::ctrl::unix::cooked
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing my question.